# Linking to generated routes from other generated routes in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app that creates solar systems and creates a route to them with the following code

```
 <Route
          exact
          path="/:id"
          render={(props) => <GenerateSystem {...props} />}
        />
```

This is working fine, and my `GenerateSystem` component creates several planets that themselves should have routes to their own pages.

My GenerateSystem component

```
<MiniPlanet
          name={`planets/${makeid()}`}
          label={``}
          className={`${planetTypes[Math.floor(Math.random() * 56 + 1)]} 
          }`}
        >
          {" "}
          
        </MiniPlanet>
```

And in my app.js I am trying to use the route like so

```
<Route exact path ="/planet/:id" component={GeneratePlanet} />
```

So far however, when I click on one of these routes for instance `http://localhost:3000/planets/p0c70v`, instead of bringing me to my `GeneratePlanet` component it will return me to the homepage. At the moment my `GeneratePlanet` component just contains a single line of text so I know the issue is not there.

What am I doing wrong with the routing? My full code is viewable [here](https://github.com/Imstupidpleasehelp/planetviewer/tree/main/src).

Comment: Pro tip: when adding `inline formatting` please just use single backticks. Triples are only necessary when creating block formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the reason

```
useEffect(() => {
    EnterSystem();
    MakeTheSystem();

    return () => {
      ExitSystem();
    };
  }, []);
```

Remove this part of the code

```
return () => {
      ExitSystem();
    };
```

To trigger an exit animation. It redirects to the "/" page.